# Count possible number of same-letter pairings in a list

Tags: python

I wish to count the number of same letter pairings in a dynamic list. For example for `my_list = ['A','A','B','B','C','C']`, there are 3 possible pairings as there is 2 `A` for 1 pair, 2 `B` for a second pair and 2 `C` for the 3rd pair. If there are 5 `A` in the list for example, it is counted as 2 pairs (2 sets of pairs of `A`)

I written some long-winded and inelegant code for this purpose which doesn't work if there are odd-numbered elements list. As such, I'm wondering if there is a more simple and readable solution.

```
my_list = ['A','A','C','C', 'D', 'D']

total_letters = len(my_list)
unpairable_letter = 0

frequency = {}

# Count frequency of each letter in list 
for letter in my_list:
    frequency[letter] = frequency.get(letter, 0) + 1

for value in frequency.values():
    if value == 1:
        unpairable_letter += 1
        
    if value > 2: 
        if value % 2 != 0:
            unpairable_letter += 1
        
print(total_letters/2 - unpairable_letter)
```

Comment: how would you handle three of the same letters in a row?  `['A', 'A', 'A']`?

Comment: `unpairable_letter + 1` doesnt do anything if you dont assign it to something

Comment: @James count it as one pair. If there are 5 As in a row, count it as 2 pair

Comment: two typos? Is this a full [mcve] of the issue still?

Comment: What exactly are "possible same letter pairings"? For `C, C, C, C` I'd have expected 6, not 2.

Comment: @tobias_k 2 of the same letters is counted as one pair. if there are 4 C, it is counted as 2 pair

Comment: So basically you just need something like `sum(lst.count(x) // 2 for x in lst)`?

Comment: @tobias_k the letters can be any letter from the alphabet, A-Z and the list might have odd elements

Comment: @tobias_k Randy wants a counting of sequential pairs of elements, where each pair gets popped when counted.

Comment: @James Is that so? I don't see this in the question or the (inelegant but working?) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use `groupby` from the `itertools` module to find the groups of letters, then get the length of the grouping and int divide by 2.  The `defaultdict` from the `collections` module is just a dictionary where a new key has a default value and type.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ['A','A','C','C', 'D', 'D']

frequency = defaultdict(int)

for x, g in  groupby(my_list):
    frequency[x] += len(tuple(g)) // 2

frequency
# returns:
defaultdict(int, {'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1})
```

In the case the a running series of letters that are an odd number, it will round down.  So 5 letters is 2 groups.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ['A','A','A','A','A','C','C','D','D','C','C']

frequency = defaultdict(int)

for x, g in  groupby(my_list):
    frequency[x] += len(tuple(g)) // 2

frequency
# returns:
defaultdict(int, {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 1})
```

#### Without imports:

Doing this without imports entails iterating over the list, check if the element from the list has changed, then add up the lengths.

```
my_list = ['A','A','A','A','A','C','C','D','D','C','C']
frequency = {}

candidate = my_list[0]
count = 0

for x in my_list:
    if x == candidate:
        count += 1
    else:
        frequency[candidate] = frequency.setdefault(candidate, 0) + count // 2
        candidate = x
        count = 1

frequency
# returns:
{'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
```

Comment: is there a solution that doesn't make use of importing? I haven't learnt to that point yet

Comment: Sure there is!  However, both of these imports are part of the standard library, so are always included with Python.  You would just end up rewriting the functions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using pandas.Series:

```
my_list = pd.Series(['A','A','C','C', 'D','A','C','C'])

my_list = my_list.value_counts()//2
my_list
```

That prints:

```
C    2
A    1
D    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python's [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

The following prints 1 because there is an even number of `A`s and even number of `C`s and an odd number of `D`s.

```python
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['A','A','C','C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
total_letters = len(my_list)

unpairable_letter = 0

count = Counter(my_list)

for num in count:
    if count[num] == 1:
        unpairable_letter += 1
    elif count[num] % 2:
        unpairable_letter += 1

print(unpairable_letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

no use of any other import but need two `for-loops` to do the work. FYI

```
my_list = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D']

char_dict = {}
char_pair_dict = {}

# get count
for c in my_list:
    if c not in char_dict.keys():
        char_dict[c] = 1
    else:
        char_dict[c] += 1

# get pair
for i in char_dict.keys():
    char_pair_dict[i] = char_dict[i] // 2
```

so `char_pair_dict` will be `{'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}` after then.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to floor-divide `//` the count of each element by two and get the `sum` of those:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D']
frequency = Counter(my_list)
print(sum(frequency[x] // 2 for x in frequency))  # 4
```